# Share app with FBConnect

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook, fbconnect

I'm using FBConnect to post messages on facebook. I'm able to let the user log in and post on his wall. The thing I don't know is how to share the app. I tried to put the itunes link of the app in the message, but it post a link to itunes as I wrote. Is it possible to add the app icon etc ... as it is when you put the link directly on facebook ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure Facebook would let you post URLs with a different scheme than http. Otherwise, people could be sharing all kinds of nasty stuff on Facebook. Best bet would be to link to a site that has a redirect to the iTunes link, but make sure you redirect using JavaScript. Facebook can follow meta refresh tags.